# What is the product of every prime ideal?

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, maximal-and-prime-ideals

Let $R$ be a commutative ring with unity, and let $\{ \mathfrak{p}_i \}_I$ be an indexing of all of the prime ideals in $R$.

Then, it is known that $\bigcap_I \mathfrak{p}_i$ is equal to $N$, the nilradical of $R$.

From a first course in number fields, I know that the intersection of ideals can sometimes be considered as the $\text{lcm}$ of the ideals in question. Thus, this naturally seems to suggest the question: what is the product of every prime ideal in $R$?

Define:

$$ \prod_I \mathfrak{p}_i = \bigcap_{J \subseteq I \text{ finite}}\bigg(\prod_J \mathfrak{p}_j \bigg)$$

Is there any similarly appealing characterisation of this ideal, as there is for the intersection of all prime ideals?

In general, it holds that $\prod_{i=1}^n \mathfrak{a}_i \subseteq \mathfrak{a}_1 \cap \cdots \cap \mathfrak{a}_n$ with equality, for example, if the $(\mathfrak{a}_i)$ are pairwise coprime. In any case, we clearly have:

$$\prod_{I} \mathfrak{p}_i \subseteq N$$

Thus, the two notions will certainly not disagree in any integral domain.

The prime ideals of $R$ clearly cannot be coprime if $R$ is a local ring, so it seems sensible to try look at local rings for clues. However, the local rings I have met only have one prime ideal -- so we trivially have equality -- and I have only just started studying localisation, so I cannot construct other examples myself for now.

Comment: It does agree! When $I$ is finite, then for every $J\subset I$, $\prod_J\mathfrak p_j\supset\prod_I\mathfrak p_j$, so the intersection is simply $\prod_I\mathfrak p_j$. I think it's a reasonable definition.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example where the two notions disagree: Let $k$ be a field. If $R=k[x,y]/(x^2)$ then its nilradical is $(x)$. However $(x,y-a)$ is a prime ideal for all $a\in k$, so the product of prime ideals is zero.

Comment: Thanks for the example! Just to be clear, I'd be looking for a characterisation (or a reason for why an elegant one does not exist) to mark an answer as accepted. Do I correctly assume that this example comes from algebraic geometry? Does this also hold for $k$ finite?

Comment: The example is a line with some nilpotent fuzz. The nilpotent radical just corresponds to reducing the scheme. On the other hand, it has infinitely many points, so the product of prime ideals is zero.

Comment: $k$ need not be finite, since more generally, $(x,p(y))$ for $p\in k[y]$ irreducible is a prime ideal. And all fields have infinitely many irreducible polynomials.

Comment: Also, I don't really expect a nice characterization in general, since I would expect the product of infinitely many prime ideals to be zero in general, unless your ring is extremely pathological.

Comment: I agree, it seems unlikely, but hopefully, it stimulates some discussion of the idea. Perhaps that is a nice auxiliary question: can anyone find a ring with $\{0\} \subset \prod \mathfrak p \subset N$? Probably not that difficult, in general -- but may be difficult as you say if there are infinitely many prime ideals.

Comment: I think that's an interesting question, maybe you can ask it as a separate question. (I don't have any immediate examples, will think about it)

Comment: Sure. Let me know if you make any progress and I can put it up.

Comment: Re $\{0\} \subset \prod \mathfrak p \subset N$: just localize your example at the origin. Then there are exactly 2 primes $(x)$ and $(x, y)$, so the product is $(xy)$ which is neither $0$ nor the nilradical $(x)$